# Unable to connect to the emulator's internet after changing the company's proxy

Tags: android-studio, proxy

They recently made a change in the proxy of the company where I work.
Since then I can't connect. The security department tried to help me but they don't know Android studio
We tried to change the proxy settings in Android studio but that doesn't help either.
If I try to open chrome, come doesn't even show a no connection error, it stays open with their logo and that's it.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

[image]

I tried to update a version in Android Studio but it does not allow me because the internet connection does not exist.
I tried logging in without a proxy and the result is the same.
I tried to log in with manual proxy parameters through the Proxy settings according to what was defined for me in information security in the company and it didn't help either.
I tried to connect with the Auto detect proxy settings and it didn't help either.